# Man page requires space to scroll, not arrow keys

Tags: command-line, 18.04, docker, manpage

On my Ubuntu 18.04 host, running `man <command>` brings up the `man` page and I can scroll up and down using the corresponding arrow keys to read the text.

On a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 docker image, I installed `man`, `man-db`, `vim` and `core-utils` and now I can only scroll down using the space bar.

Additionally, the `man` page in the docker container shows `--MORE--` in the bottom left corner while on my host it shows:

```
Manual page <COMMAND>(<INT>) line <INT> (press h for help or q to quit)
```

in the bottom left corner.

I have the same version of man on both the host and my docker image (man 2.8.3)

**What do I need to install in my docker image to allow man to scroll using arrow keys similar to how I do on my host OS?**

---

**EDIT -- Additional output from the docker container**

```
root@11aa9a0948e7:~# man --version
man 2.8.3
root@11aa9a0948e7:~# echo $MANPAGER

root@11aa9a0948e7:~# echo $PAGER

root@11aa9a0948e7:~# update-alternatives --query pager
Name: pager
Link: /usr/bin/pager
Slaves:
 pager.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/pager.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /bin/more
Value: /bin/more

Alternative: /bin/more
Priority: 50
Slaves:
 pager.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/more.1.gz
```

**Same output from the Host OS**

```
user@host:~$ man --version
man 2.8.3
user@host:~$ echo $MANPAGER

user@host:~$ echo $PAGER

user@host:~$ update-alternatives --query pager
 Name: pager
Link: /usr/bin/pager
Slaves:
 pager.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/pager.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /bin/less
Value: /bin/less

Alternative: /bin/less
Priority: 77
Slaves:
 pager.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz

Alternative: /bin/more
Priority: 50
Slaves:
 pager.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/more.1.gz
```

Comment: @steeldriver output has been added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You system uses `more` as page for `man` while a standard Ubuntu installation uses `less`.

Install the package `less`

Comment: Worked like a charm. I did so as soon as I noticed that less was installed as a pager. Thanks!